# How do i write the literal "]]>" inside a CDATA section without it ending the section

Tags: xml, cdata

Pretty simple question, I'm writing an XML document and i'm not sure how to write "]]>" without it being seen as the end of the section.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
]]>]]&gt;<![CDATA[
```

This ends up breaking the CDATA section in two parts, but it's what you have to do.

Comment: Better answer IMHO than in the duplicate :)

Comment: Paolo: think of it that way: CDATA is an area where you don't have to (and in fact can't) escape *anything*. How would you mark the end of such an area?

Comment: The length (in bytes) could be a required attribute. I absolutely agree with Paolo: Yikes.

Answer (score 9):

I think

```
<![CDATA[]]]]><![CDATA[>]]>
```

is the way to go.

That is:

- one CDATA section containing the literal string `]]` (`<![CDATA[]]]]>`)
- one CDATA section containing the literal string `>` (`<![CDATA[>]]>`)

In practice, there would probably be text before the first `]]` and/or after the `>`

See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections

Comment: I don't know if this is the right answer or not, but if so, it's the worst right answer ever.  (No offence intended...I'm commenting on the miserableness of the system, rather than your answer.)

Answer (score 5):

You can't. CDATA doesn't provide any way to escape characters, so those characters will always represent the end of the CDATA section. You can, however, let them end the CDATA section, add "`]]&gt;`" and start a new one with "`<![CDATA[`".

This way the String "`]]>]]&gt;<![CDATA[`" has almost the effect of being an escape for "`]]>" in a CDATA section.