# encode ]]> in a cdata

Tags: xml, cdata

If I'm building some XML and using `<![CDATA[...]]>`, how do I encode data that may include a `]]>` substring? would it be `]]&gt;`?  I ask because I always thought CDATA content was literal content.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538163/how-do-i-write-the-literal-inside-a-cdata-section-with-it-ending-the-section

Answer (score 8):

It's not terribly efficient, or easy to read, or anything, but [an approach to this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Uses_of_CDATA_sections) appears to be writing..

```
]]]]><![CDATA[>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use two cdata tags, the first one contains ]] and the second one contains >

Answer (score -1):

CDATA is literal content in a sense, but of course there has to be some way to mark the end of a CDATA block and whatever you choose is going to have to be represented in your string somehow.

When I had to deal with XML documents containing CDATAs inside another CDATA block like you seem to have to, I gave up and encoded the whole thing as Base64. The other side then extracts the text and decodes it.

Base64 is handy because it has common support and/or simple algorithms to code and decode ASCII strings into it in many languages, in my case C# and Javascript in an ASP.NET app.

Answer (score -2):

Shouldn't entities work?

like this: &93;&93;`&gt;`

or, just one of them: ]]`&gt;`

93 is for latin1, you would need unicode entities if sending data in utf-8.

As a sidenote, there are other characters which are dissallowed in a CDATA-block aswell, some weird quotations and control-flow characters.